# Sublime text 2 и терминал Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, sublime-text

Погугли, но ответа не нашел. Может кто встречал решение. У меня ubuntu 13.10, использую sublime text 2 и как бы вот задача: мне совместно с sublime text 2 постоянно нужно работать еще и с терминалом ubuntu. Можно ее как-то открыть прямо в sublime text 2? Или можно как-нибудь настроить сочетание клавиш в sublime text 2, который бы запускал консольный скрипт?

Спасибо!

Comment: насколько я знаю это не возможно, тебе нужен vim или emacs

Comment: Спасибо, но я еще подожду ответов =)

Comment: Мне самому интересно, когда то задавался таким же вопросом))